# Generating Alternative Initial Value while wrapping keys with AES

Tags: node.js, aes

Am following the instructions on https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5649#section-3 and I have gotten to a point where I need to generate the `LSB(32,A)` for the **Alternative Initial Value (AIV)**. Am using [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/) with [buffers](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) to implement the algorithm. My understanding is `32-bits === buffer.length == 4` or in other words, length 4 of buffer is the 32-bits referenced in the article. I have padded the key after converting it buffer then padding with the length value of `8 - (length % 8)` with `0s` as value as indicated in the article. Now the thing I have not been able to figure out is getting the value of `32-bit MLI`. How do I get the `MLI`, I just know its `Message Length Indicator` but thats all I know about it.

Example:

```
const key = Buffer.from('base64 key', 'base64');
const kek = Buffer.from('A65959A6', 'hex');
```

Now here I have only `MSB(32, A)` but not `LSB(32, A)`, how do I get the value, and is there anything I am doing wrong, please help I have already spent alot of time trying to figure this out.

**Scenario:** Let's say my key length is 75, now I have to pad the remaining 5 characters for it to be multiples of 8, now how do I generate `LSB(32, A)` in this case?

Comment: _...How do I get the MLI,...?_ From your link: _The 32-bit MLI, which occupies the low-order half of the AIV, is an unsigned binary integer equal to the octet length of the plaintext key data, in network order -- that is, with the most significant octet first._

Comment: Now that, I read, but am not quite getting it, so looking for abit more elaboration/explanation, thats where am stuck @Topaco

Comment: I would suspect: Number of bytes of the plaintext, stored on 4 bytes in BE, thus: MLI=0x0000004b. If your actual question is whether the padding is counted, I would guess no with regard to steps 1)-3) in section 3.

Comment: @Topaco surprisingly, I did not know how to arrive to that but just a while ago,  i did add the padding and did the conversion, so what i did, i eventually retrieved the original number, but I had kept it aside to implement as a hack, but now thanks to you, i have a good feeling about what i arrived at